# cannot establish a connection to jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I creating a new database connection with MySQL it shows an error

```
Unable to add connection. Cannot establish a connection to
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3360/alpha using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver(Access
denied for user @ 'localhost' using password : YES
```

Comment: i have tried the steps that is given in the page but at the 8th step i am getting the error

Comment: ok i got my answer. thanks to all